# Tree edges different coloring

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

I want to make tree with each node has valency of three. I got the below code online somewhere. The first level has valency three however second and third level has valency four, and I also want to color the child different from parent and just want to use three colors. (e.g if parent is red then the branches will be green and blue)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,snakes}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance= 32mm,sibling angle=120]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance= 16mm,sibling angle=60]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance = 12mm,sibling angle=30]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[fill]
%\tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[segment length=1mm,
%                              segment angle=10,draw]
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow cyclic,shape=circle,very thick,level distance=13mm,
                    cap=round]
\node {} child [color=\A] foreach \A in {red,green,blue}
    { node {} child [color=\A!50!\B] foreach \B in {red, green,blue}
        { node {} child [color=\A!50!\B!50!\C] foreach \C in {red,green,blue}
            { node {} }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I am new in using tikz and didn't feel comfortable in working with it so far.

Comment: Please add `\end{document}` and use `\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance= 32mm,sibling angle=120}` and likewise for the other styles. And please explain what "valency" means. My current interpretation suggests it is not possible to achieve this with 3 colors only if a parent has more than 2 children.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very similar to [Andrew's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449386/121799) except that parents and children have different colors. **EDIT**: removed a superfluous `\index`, big thanks to Andrew! **@nd EDIT**: Simplification with `\pgfkeysalso`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,snakes}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\xdef\mycolor{black}
\xdef\ColorList{{"red","green!60!black","blue"}}
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance= 32mm,sibling angle=120},
level 2/.style={level distance= 16mm,sibling angle=60},
level 3/.style={level distance = 12mm,sibling angle=30},
every node/.append style={fill},
my color/.code={\pgfmathparse{\ColorList[mod(#1,3)]}
\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/color/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow cyclic,shape=circle,very thick,level distance=13mm,
                    cap=round]
\node {} child [my color=\A] foreach \A in {0,1,2}
    { node {} child [my color=\A+\B+1] foreach \B in  {0,1}
        { node {} child [my color=\A+\B+\C+2] foreach \C in  {0,1}
            { node {} }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Very cute! :) Part of me is unhappy that you are redefining the `\index` command but of course this doesn't matter since everything happens inside a group.

Comment: @Andrew Good point. Will fix it.

Answer (score 6):

If you want each vertex to have valence 3 then you should loop over only two colours for the child nodes. This produces:

[image]

Here is the modified code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,snakes}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance= 32mm,sibling angle=120]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance= 16mm,sibling angle=60]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance = 12mm,sibling angle=30]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[fill]
%\tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[segment length=1mm,
%                              segment angle=10,draw]
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow cyclic,shape=circle,very thick,level distance=13mm,
                    cap=round]
\node {} child [color=\A] foreach \A in {red,green,blue}
    { node {} child [color=\A!50!\B] foreach \B in {red, green}
        { node {} child [color=\A!50!\B!50!\C] foreach \C in {red,green}
            { node {} }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. I did this earlier myself however my problem is also colors. The red parent should not have red child directly.

Comment: @Touseef Sorry, didn't notice your colour requirement but marmot seems to have sorted it out.

Comment: Yeah he did it. I am now trying to understand his magic code lines :-)

Comment: @Touseef It's just a clever use of mod 3 arithmetic combined with the list of three colours defined in `\ColorList`.